# Why doesn't Superset refresh when I add a new column to a connected table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

I can smoothly connect my MySQL database to Superset and create a table, slice and dashboard, but when I add a new column in the table in MySQL, the table I created in Superset would not change or refresh the schema.

In order to solve the problem, I have to delete the old tables, slice and dashboard and connect again to rebuild them, which doesn't make sense.

Is there any way I can refresh schema in superset when table schema in MySQL is modified?

Answer (score 4):

- Superset v. 1.0.0
- postgreSQL

when schema is changed, just refreshing the schema in table edit won't add the new columns. You have to click:
[image]

Comment: Can we automatically Refresh/Update the columns? Meaning to automatically click "Sync columns from source" using a script or a scheduled app?

Comment: When I clicked that all columns disappeared.

Comment: Why the button is disabled for me